# Getting Wrong response from youtube data api while getting user info

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using the following api for getting user profile after authenticating my google account

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default?access_token={user_token}
The response from the above api is :

**NoLinkedYouTubeAccount**

I already accessed my youtube account with google account credentials but the response is NoLinkedYouTubeAccount.please suggest me where iam doing wrong

Comment: have u created your channel on you tube using your google account?

Comment: did u mean subscription to channels? yes i had subscribed

Comment: are you passing correct username and password?

Comment: Corporate google accounts are administrated a bit different from general accounts, are you using one of them ?

Comment: No i'm not using that but i didn't gave my mobile number and alternate email while registering google account. Does it the reason for that response